# Avoid :focus styles when clicking on div (only on tab key)

Tags: html, css

In my following minimal example I have a div that acts as a button. It has a tabindex, so if I use the tab key and get to the element, the style of the class `.with-focus` is applied. So far so good.

But I get the style of the class `.with-focus` as well when clicking with the mouse on the button. And this is what I do **NOT** want. Is it possible to avoid?

```css
.with-focus[tabindex]:focus {
 outline: 5px solid green;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn with-focus" tabindex="0" onclick="console.log('clicked')">
  Button
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good link. But it does seem like a lot of overly complicated css for something jq can do with the `.blur()` method. Like a one liner `$('.with-focus').mouseup(function() { this.blur() })`

Comment: Yes, in my case JS is the best approach, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the :active substate, try adding this after the :focus selector

```
.with-focus[tabindex]:active {
  outline: 0;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/agustinrhcp/pen/LKdWEy)

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not work in Firefox.

Comment: What does not work on firefox? the :active selector does https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aactive

Comment: Because in Firefox when clicking with the mouse on the button it gets the style of the class .with-focus